# Is there a way for me to copy the oriuentation of an object in blender game to another while the game is active?

Tags: game-engine

So I needed a way to reset the 3rd person camera view, since the camera seems a little wonky. I'm able to have a proper reset 50% of the time, reverting the camera to the same orientation of an empty group just like I want it to. The other 50% of the time it's flipped 180 degrees in the wrong direction. Does it have something to do with the fact I used a secondary mouse control to allow the character to be observed without changing its faced direction?

I essentially just want the camera to have a reset-able view after someone looks at their own character.
 I've been using track-to in order to copy the rotation to the camera.

I'd be fine with it if a coin toss didn't determine the success of the program working.

Comment: Please provide an img of your logic editor and scripts if using some, [this](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/93359/damped-steeringseek-via-python/93499#93499) may give you and idea.

Comment: I'm unclear what exactly you want to achieve. Where is the camera located? Where is it looking too? When and how do you want to change these two parameters?

Answer (score 0):

[Api reference localOrientation](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bge.types.KX_GameObject.html?highlight=local%20orientation#bge.types.KX_GameObject.localOrientation)

```
from bge import logic

scene = logic.getCurrentScene()
own = logic.getCurrentController().owner # Cube.001
obj = scene.objects["Cube"]
print("obj",obj.localOrientation)
print("obj",obj.localOrientation.to_euler())
print("own",own.localOrientation)
print("own",own.localOrientation.to_euler())
obj.localOrientation = own.localOrientation
print("obj",obj.localOrientation)
print("obj",obj.localOrientation.to_euler())
print("own",own.localOrientation)
print("own",own.localOrientation.to_euler())
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Who about multiple cameras?

- One for general view.
- One for character A.
- One for character B.
- ...

Then switch between the cameras.